# Declare string variable in riemann config file

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am newbie and facing a very strange issue. I did a lot of search but could not find solution to it. I am actually trying to define a string variable in my riemann config file. I am using syntax as given below

```
(streams
  (def mystr "system manager is launching br123 on dir01")
  ;(prn mystr)
  ;(def myfind (re-find #"system manager is launching (\S+) on (\S+)" mystr))
  ;(pr-str myfind)
  ;(pr-str (get myfind 1))
)
```

Everytime, I run riemann, it gives me below error
*java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn*

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your constants outside the `(streams .... )` expression.

the streams macro is trying to run it as if it where a function. I like to define all constants at the top of the config file though that's just personal preference.